# Proof of (F U E) x (G ∩ H)= [(E x G) ∩ (E x H)] U [(F x G) ∩ (F x H)]

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been struggling to find the correct way to prove this property, I hope someone can help me with this. 
the property: 
F, E, G, H are sets.

(F U E) x (G ∩ H)= [(E x G) ∩ (E x H)] U [(F x G) ∩ (F x H)]

Thank you.

Ps: I signed up to ask this question, this is my first time on this website, I don't know how to use Mathjax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in set theory we have to prove that $A=B$ we proceed to show that $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$. So assume that $(x,y)\in (F\cup E)\times (G\cap H)$. Then we have $x\in F\cup E$ and $y\in G\cap H$. So $x\in F$ or $x\in E$, and $y\in G$ and $y\in H$. This leads us to two possibilities. First, if $x\in F$, then $(x,y)\in (F\times G)\cap (F\times H)\subseteq [(E\times G)\cap (E\times H)]\cup [(F\times G)\cap (F\times H)]$, therefore $(F\cup E)\times (G\cap H)\subseteq [(E\times G)\cap (E\times H)]\cup [(F\times G)\cap (F\times H)]$. Now, if $x\in E$, we have $(x,y)\in (E\times G)\cap (E\times H)\subseteq [(E\times G)\cap (E\times H)]\cup [(F\times G)\cap (F\times H)]$, so again $(F\cup E)\times (G\cap H)\subseteq [(E\times G)\cap (E\times H)]\cup [(F\times G)\cap (F\times H)]$.

The reverse inclusion can be proved in the same manner.

Comment: I tried to proceed by equivalence, but I ended up in a huge mess of "or"s. Your answer was very helpful, thank you for taking the time to answer.